# Automatically retrieve correct data type per column

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, type-conversion

Is there any way, maybe an existing framework which is capable of detecting the correct datatype per column? I bulk insert CSVs into MSSQL. The standard datatype is varchar(255). I would like to cast each column to its' right datatype.

Comment: Automatically detection of data type is really hard. Is 123 a number of a string? If it's a number, is it an int, a big int, float or decimal?

Comment: In case the table already created with a certain data-types, the insert should work fine.. the DB should be able to convert the values to relevant datatype

Comment: I think in SSIS, there is an option which "suggests" correct data type.

Comment: @nabeel: Unfortunately i can't predict what kind of data is loaded into the system.

Comment: @br0ken.pipe unfortunately the database also can't predict what kind of data is loaded into the system

Comment: if you can't predict the kind of data but you must save it into the database, you can't deal with datatypes in SQL, you have to do some post-processing in your application logic.

Comment: The technique the Excel ODBC driver used was to scan the first 8 rows of each column & determine data type from that. So int might have highest priority, then float, then datetime, lastly string. If every row in the first 8 rows of that column matched the same datat type, that's what would be used. String was the final fallback case.